# How to solve the path to an imported JAR file (NetBeans 9.0)

Tags: java, netbeans, build, jar, path

**Introduction**

I am using NetBeans 9.0 with imported libraries (JAR files). Some of those I downloaded from a school's computer and others from home.

**Problem**

When I want to do the build it shows an error that it can't reach the library, even worst, I can not even remove libraries by some reason. Not even "manually" (enter the file's project and manually delete it).

[image]

In this picture you can see the build error log for some imported libraries (jsoup and jfreecharts) which by some reason can not be read.

On the right of the image you see the Edit for JSoup which shows a different path to the JAR file.

**Question**

- Why is NetBeans still looking for the previous path?
- How I am supposed to solve this path problem when I can not even remove libraries?
- How I can avoid this problem in the future?

Not using NetBeans won't be accepted as an answer.

Thanks for your interest and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head over libraries in your project

[image]

Right click on it with your mouse and then into properties

This will set you into Categories: -> Libraries.

[image]

***(Already solved the path issue that is why there are no red paths here)***

There you can see all the classpaths of your libs and if those are correct. Delete those which are on red and reimport the JARs into your project.

- Click on the path you want to delete and press Remove

**This will solve the issue AND be able able to delete libraries that you are not using anymore.**